# compelled by an overriding drive to survive and breed

Tags: meaning-in-context

Are the bold properties in the text recounting the instinctive behaviors of animals or  the human properties that through the evolution became evident in human behaviors, making them different from animals?  my problem is with the verb "compelled by". It has made the text confusing.

Context:

We do not know when feelings such as love and grief became more complex than the simple intuitions of animals compelled by **an overriding drive to survive and breed, opportunistically fondling their mates, nurturing their young or nuzzling their superiors, briefly grieving when they go**.

Art and Science  (Sian Ede)

Comment: The fact that you have to ask means we are not that different after all ;)

Comment: We've had 20 questions about this work in the last month. It seems to be exceptionally badly-written and not a good choice for a holiday assignment. [That doesn't mean asking about it is not a valid thing to do though. It's a comment on the choice of the work.]

Comment: Thank you @AndrewLeach Leach for your attention. You are right about the text, and it is why I ask questions about it time to time. I love reading this book and try to resolve the lingual ambiguities that I encounter meanwhile. However it is sometimes so difficult to decide whether my misunderstanding is the cause of confusion or the badly written text of the book! Nevertheless, effort to understand a vague text is simultaneously a lovely and painful challenge

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the intrinsic animal drive. The first part talks about human traits, everything after "than" is what the human traits are being contrasted against.